# How to create properties automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties

I have a "settings" class, which has some properties for usability and to restrict set accessor. It seems easy while i had within ten items, but then their count was increased. I need some way to create these properties automatically, something like that:

```
foreach(var property in SettingsList)
{
    _settings.AddAutoProperty(property);
}
```

It may have deal with reflection, but i can't get to efficient solution.

The properties definition:

```
public bool cbNextExcCount
{
    get { return (bool)this.GetValueById("cbNextExcCount"); }
}

public bool cbSaveOnChangeExc
{
    get { return (bool)this.GetValueById("cbSaveOnChangeExc"); }
}

public bool cbAutoIncrement
{
    get { return (bool)this.GetValueById("cbAutoIncrement"); }
}

public bool cbRememberOnExit
{
    get { return (bool)this.GetValueById("cbRememberOnExit"); }
}

...etc.
```

**UPDATE**
To summ up, i wrote the next code:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> Properties = new ExpandoObject();
private List<string> SettingsList = new List<string> 
{ 
    "cbNextExcCount",
    "cbSaveOnChangeExc",
    "cbAutoIncrement",
    "cbRememberOnExit"
};

public void CreateProperties()
{
    foreach (string SettingName in SettingsList)
    {
        Properties.Add(SettingName, () => this.GetValueById(SettingName));
    }
}
```

But i have an error on `() => this.GetValueById("cbNextExcCount"))`:

argument type 'lambda expression' is not assignable to parameter type 'object'.

I can store `Func<bool>`, but settings may have other type than bool and if i use Func, it's get a bit more complicate to call.

Comment: What is the criteria for the properties? Start with "cb"?

Comment: @AmiramKorach in the form of Hungarian that led everyone to despise it (as opposed to the original form, that some people still defend) "cb" means a class-level boolean, though of course that's clearly pointless here.

Comment: does `cb` means there are check box behind that? If yes, what don't you use some kind of databinding? You should describe what you are trying to do, not only how. I feel there will be more simple and elegant solutions than yours.

Comment: You can't create properties dynamically at runtime and use them statically in your code... Are you trying to generate the properties at design/compile time ?

Comment: "cb" means checkbox, and there are other properties (for comboboxes, etc.)
So, properties can't be created dynamically. Sad, but i don't really into data-bindings, so may be it's better to learn more about it, may be i'll found the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't create auto-properties, but you can use an `ExpandoObject`.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, because using expandos means using *duck typing* (i.e. dynamic programming).

`ExpandoObject` sample:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.PropertyA = "Hello";
expando.PropertyB = "world!";
```

An interesting thing about expandos is that `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, meaning that you can upcast any expando to this type and iterate over its added properties, which could be great for storing run-time created settings.

**UPDATE**

I was thinking more about a good solution and if `SettingList` is a custom class developed by yourself, maybe you can add a property called `Custom` to `SettingList` and add there settings that aren't added during design-time.

**UPDATE 2**

In your case, instead of storing the actual value of something, you could add `Func<bool>` to `ExpandoObject`'s run-time settings:

```
IDictionary<string, object> settings = new ExpandoObject();
settings.Add("cbNextExcCount", () => this.GetValueById("cbNextExcCount"));
```

Actually, I don't know `this` scope in your code sample, but change `this` to anything that could be an instance of `SettingList` or whatever.

Once you've added run-time settings, you can type `settings` variable to `dynamic` typing in order to access properties like this:

```
dynamic allSettings = (dynamic)settings;
bool cbNextExcCount = allSettings.cbNextExcCount();
```

Comment: ) I've already tried to store Func(bool) before you wrote update 2, like that:

    settings.cbNextExcCount = new Func<bool>(() => (bool)this.GetValueById("cbNextExcCount"));

But if i'm try to use you code, i have an error on "() => this.GetValueById("cbNextExcCount"))":

argument type "lambda expression" is no assignable to parameter type 'object'

Comment: @LblSS BTW, check how I did it in my answer. I'm upcasting to `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: @LblSS Other detail: you don't need to cast your value to bool, since you're using dynamic typing. It's useless, because type checking will occur during run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider Expando Objects in System.Dynamic namespace. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121472/An-introduction-to-Expando-Object-Dotnet-4-0) article can be a good start.